# how do i add the post list to a newly admin panel in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, admin

I have created a new sub menu for a custom post type in wordpress admin, and I would like to add the a modified list of posts in there, i accordance to the newly variables that i have in my database; is there a function in wordpress to display the post lists? or do i have to do it manually?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');
function my_plugin_menu() {
add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=product', __( 'My product list', 'zeeneo-tenders' ), __( 'My product list', 'woo-tenders' ), 'manage_options', 'my-products', 'my_plugin_options');

}
function my_plugin_options() {
if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))  {
   wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
}
  echo "<h2>" . __( 'My products list', 'zeeneo-tenders' ) . "</h2>";

  // Here is the code to display the list of posts in this new panel
}
```

Comment: Not really understanding .. do you want to add the post list as `menu items` ? otherwise ,the custom post type will already give you an `edit` screen..

Comment: Here is the deal, i have installed the woocommerce, and i would like to add a submenu which lists the products that have certain attributes; apart from the woocommerce's main product list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't have `wp_dropdown_posts` just like it has `wp_dropdown_categories` and `wp_dropdown_users`.

It has to be made by hand with `get_posts` or `WP_Query`, loop the results and make the `<select><option>`. For your use case, I think you'll need to use the [Custom Fields parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

You can find a sample code at WPSE: [Dropdown list of a custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/34320/12615).